# Regular Expressions for DER signature hex (also req, address, TxIDs)?

Tags: python

I'm using Python (2.7) and its `re` module for recognition of various Bitcoin data, namely:

> addresses, DER sigs, OP Return hexdata, TxIDs

I've been using `re.compile`: for example, for a valid Tx hash (TxID):

```
RE_TXHASH = re.compile('^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$')
if bool(re.match(RE_TXHASH, 'f'*64)):    # 'f'*63 would fail
    print 'valid tx hash!'
else:
    raise Exception("invalid tx hash!")
```

I'm looking for regex patterns for the following (or input on my current best attempt):

1. DER signatures: General format *`"30[sig_size]02[r_size]02[s_size][sighash]"`*
2. Bitcoin addresses:  `re.compile('^[123mn]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{26,33}$')`
3. OP Return hex strings: `re.compile('^(6a){1}[a-fA-F0-9]{0,80}$')`
4. TxIDs: `re.compile('^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$')`

**EDIT**: to clarify, can someone help with a regex pattern for this? *`"30[sig_size]02[r_size]02[s_size][sighash]"`*

Comment: Not all signatures in the Bitcoin block chain are DER. `OP_RETURN` prefixed outputs don't have to be 80 bytes.

Comment: [quote]Not all signatures in the Bitcoin block chain are DER.[/quote] Is there an example for non-DER signature in blockchain?

Comment: @Bitcoin I'm looking to recognise just DER signatures with regex, so I'm open to any suggestions for the regex pattern. Re OP_RETURN, isn't the regex saying between 0 and 80? (Honest question)

Comment: @amaclin All of the ones with unnecessary amounts of padding on the values are BER not DER. You must use the smallest possible encoding for DER rules.

Comment: Yes the regex is saying between one and eighty, but that's not a requirement of the data type.

Comment: WRT the OP_RETURN: You're missing the data push byte. The data doesn't start immediately after the return. Also, 80 bytes is standard, but not required by consensus.

Comment: @NickODell Expecting a certain data push type is ill advised, push types are malleable and not always used consistently. 80 bytes you could use `0x50` for a direct push, `0x4c50` for `PUSHDATA1`, or `0x4d0050` for `PUSHDATA2`, or `0x4e00000050` for `PUSHDATA4`. Regular expressions isn't ideal for this task, especially for BER signatures.

Comment: @amaclin Some altcoins also now contain the bytes to trigger the OpenSSL 32bit consensus failure.

Comment: @Bitcoin How did we reach discussing altcoins, DER/BER and OP_RETURN ahead of my question on regexs? **Me:** `I'm looking to recognise just DER signatures with regex, so I'm open to any suggestions for the regex pattern.` seems pretty clear and independent of DER/BER classification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DER sigs, it's possible for R or S to be very small.

1. DER sigs: `re.compile('^30[0-9a-fA-F]{72,136}02[0-9a-fA-F]{0,64}02[0-9a-fA-F]{0,64}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}')`

Bitcoin addresses cannot have a 0. Also the {1} is superfluous

2. Bitcoin addresses: `re.compile('^[123mn][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,33}$')`

Again, {1} is superfluous for OP_RETURN. Also, the a might be capitalized.

3. OP Return hex strings: `re.compile('^6[aA][a-fA-F0-9]{0,80}$')`

TXIDs are fine

Comment: Ring a ding ding. Thank you **for answering the question**: I get that it's SO and pedantic semantics are to be expected...  +250 bounty headed your way for the concise answer!

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie You should probably test the regex before accepting the answer.

Comment: You might want to consider using '([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]){X}' instead of '[0-9a-fA-F]{2X}', to capture the fact that the hex chars must come in pairs.

Comment: I ended up using: `ur'''30(?P<siglen>[0-4][0-9a-f])02(?P<rlen>[0-2][0-9a-f])(?P<r>(?:00)?[a-f0-9]{2,64})02(?P<slen>[0-2][0-9a-f])(?P<s>(?:00)?[a-f0-9]{2,64})(?P<sighash>(0|8)[0-3])?'''`